# Help!! Blender wont Zoom. Says moved object to master collection instead

Tags: objects, navigation, tools

Really need help here. Blender wont zoom in. It will zoom out all I want but when I scroll to go in it just gives me a message at the bottom that 'objects moved to master collection'. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: 1. This is a help section, so the word is not necessary. I would also abstain from ! in a title. 
2. With your mouse over any selected object, press '.' on the numpad. Or view -> frame selected. 
That is my guess on what your question refers to, otherwise please specify if the camera won't zoom in render.

Comment: The '.' thing works to get to an object but doesnt fix the zoom problem. Im in object mode.

Comment: zoom as in camera movement in the viewport? Getting closer to your object from any angle?